# force hibernate insertion under @Transactional method to happen in the same order they received

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm saving 2 entries to the same table 1 by 1 with JPA and Hibernate under some Transactional flow chain.

the entries are not committed until the transaction is over of course,
but weirdly they are saved to the table in the opposite order.

for example:
t1: transactional flow invoked
t2: entry 1 saved to table X
t3: entry 2 saved to table X
t4: the transaction is over.

when I check the table I can see entry 2 received a lower id then entry 1.

is there something I can do in order to force hibernate to persist in the order I intended?

Answer (score 0):

You can flush the persistence context after calling `persist` for entry1 by calling `EntityManager.flush()`.

Comment: this is not working. entries are not committed before @Transactional flow ends.

Comment: You can't commit a transaction from within a `@Transactional` method. The interceptor will take care of the committing. You asked for `saved to table` and flushing is what causes the insert statements to be emitted to the DB. If you want these entries to become visible to other transactions, you will have to commit your transaction i.e. by using `@Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW)`.